# Comparator for Comparable

Tags: java

I'm trying to sort a collection in the regular or reversed order depending on the value of `order` variable:

```
class LogEvent implements Comparable<LogEvent>{...}


void process(List<LogEvent> events, final boolean order){
    Comparator<LogEvent> regularComparator = new Comparator<LogEvent>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(LogEvent o1, LogEvent o2) {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    };
    Collections.sort(events, (order) ? regularComparator : Collections.reverseOrder());
}
```

However the fact that I need to introduce anonymous class kills the beauty of ternary operator.

*Is there a standard way to get the `regularComparator` without introduction of anonymous classes?*

Note: I could have create a comparator which works as a regular or reversed comparator using  `return order ? o1.compareTo(o2) : o2.compareTo(o1);`, but that is not the question.

Comment: You can move it to its own class, you know. Anonymous classes can **always** be replaced by an *actual* class declaration.

Comment: I'm just explaining where the question is coming from

Comment: And I'm suggesting a *standard way* to do what you're asking.

Comment: `public class RegularComparator implements Comparator<LogEvent> ...`

Comment: So introduce Comparator class instead of making original class Comparable?

Comment: Maybe instead of the inner class you will do a regular Collections.sort(events) if order is normal else Collections.sort(events, Collections.reverseOrder()). It isn't ideal, but still cleaner than an inner class

Comment: This is how I actually started. if...else...; If we had Collections.regularOrder() that would be the cleanest...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `LogEvent` implements `Comparable<LogEvent>` as you say then you don't need to write a Comparator at all:

```
if (order) {
    Collections.sort(events);
} else {
    Collections.sort(events, Collections.reverseOrder());
}
```

**EDIT:** A solution that will work with the ternary operator:

```
Collections.sort(events, order ? null : Collections.reverseOrder());
```

This takes advantage of this documented feature of `Collections.sort(List list, Comparator c)`:

> c - the comparator to determine the order of the list. A null value indicates that the elements' natural ordering should be used.

Comment: The use of the comparator provided by Collections.reverseOrder() requires that the object being sorted is `Comparable` anyway.

Comment: Yes, the documentation for `Collections.sort()` says: "All elements in the list must implement the Comparable interface."  The documentation for `Collections.reverseOrder()` makes a similar restriction: "a comparator that imposes the reverse of the natural ordering on a collection of objects that implement the Comparable interface. (The natural ordering is the ordering imposed by the objects' own compareTo method.)"